# copy lines containing word from one file to another file in linux

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I want to copy lines containing certain words from `file1` to `file2`.

Suppose `file1`:

```
ram 100 ct 50
gopal 200 bc 40
ravi 50 ct 40
krishna 200 ct 100
```

`file2` should have only the lines containing "ct", which would look like this:

```
ram 100 ct 50
ravi 50 ct 40
krishna 200 ct 100
```

Which is the best way to achieve this? I had a file of 200mb.
I used `grep` but I didn't get any result running `grep -n ct file1`.

Comment: How do you select what word should be copied? I do not see `gopal` in file `2`, why not?

Comment: Hello Jotne I am searching for `ct' in file1 and copying lines containing `ct` to file2

Answer (score 14):

This `awk` should do

```
awk '/ct/' file1 > file2
```

If position is important

```
awk '$3=="ct"' file1 > file2
awk '$3~/ct/' file1 > file2
```

last version is ok if `ct` is part of some in field #3

---

Same with `grep`

```
grep ct file1 > file2
```

`-n` is not needed, since it prints line number

---

Same with `sed`

```
sed -n '/ct/p' file1 > file2
```

Comment: This will match `/ct/` against the whole line, not just the third column which is apparently what OP wants (`krishnact 200 bc 100` would also match). Also, the regex is not anchored which might or might not be desired but is worth noting.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth OP does not specify that it needed to be in field #3, but for code robustness, its a better approach to specify field.

Comment: No, they didn't word it like that but it is obvious from the example input/output. The first column is obviously a name and should not match.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late, but just wanted to add that you can do this in vim. Create a copy of the file, then run

```
:g!/pattern/d
```

(delete all lines not having the pattern)

so,

```
:g!/^\w+ \d+ ct \d+/      \\ view the lines
:g!/^\w+ \d+ ct \d+/d     \\ delete lines
```

More commands can be found [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g).

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep -n '\bct\b' file1 > file2
```

By the way, grep -n selects lines together with line numbers. If that's not your intention then `grep ct file1 > file2` would suffice.

Comment: This will also match lines where `ct` is part of the name in the first column which I doubt is what OP wants and might produce false positives.

Comment: indeed. fixed the pattern

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$3=="ct"' file1 > file2
```

This only filters lines where the third column must exactly match the string `ct`.