# how to grep line number of string , copy same line in other file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

Instead of grep , I used awk here. The file pkg.conf has 'ssl_cipher' string , I need to copy the line containing ssl_cipher to another file 'pkg.conf.new' at the same line number (here it`s 20 in pkg.conf):

```
bash-4.2$ awk '/ssl_cipher/ {print FNR,$(NF-1),$NF}' pkg.conf
20 ssl_cipher 'ECDHJES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES :RSA+AESGCMHaNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DESHSSLv3');
```

Is there an awk one liner to do this or should I seek the help of 'sed' ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [copy lines containing word from one file to another file in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22319345/copy-lines-containing-word-from-one-file-to-another-file-in-linux)

Comment: @n00b: It's not. The requirement here is to replace a given line in the second file.

Comment: [edit] your question to include sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this awk script:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{               # On the first file
       if(/ssl_cipher/){    # lookup the string
         line_content=$0;   # store the content
         line_no=NR         # and line number
       };
       next                 # skip other files
     }
     FNR==line_no{          # On the second file, at the wanted line 
       print line_content   # append the wanted content
     }1                     # print the other lines
     ' pkg.conf pkg-new.conf
```

Note that will insert a new line. As mentionned by @Yoric, if you want to replace the line, and the `next` keyword after the `print line_content`.

The result is output to the stdout. If you want to replace the `pkg-new.conf` file, and if you have GNU awk, you can add the option `-i inplace` to the command line.

Comment: That's a great solution using awk. As far as I understand, however, the replaced line should not be followed by the initial line, thus you could add a new line with `next` right after the line `print line_content`

Comment: The result is not "output to the screen".  The output is written to stdout, which *may* be a tty but usually is not.  To conflate stdout with "the screen" is a great evil.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Ok... Sorry for my bad english wording... Do not hesitate to correct the spelling mistake in this answer

Comment: @Yoric I'd use `$0=line_content` instead of `print line_content; next` to replace that line. You already have a print for the 2nd file (done by `1`) so you should avoid adding a second print so there's fewer places to have to change if you want to decorate each output line, for example.

Comment: @Ed Morton smart choice indeed, It feels weird to me that we can modify the $0 (in some languages modifying the input can have side effects). In the end, I still like your solution better.

Comment: It does have side-effects in that it updates NF and re-splits the record but those are usually desirable, or at least not harmful, side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed to generate a sed script:

```
awk '/ssl_cipher/ {print FNR,$(NF-1),$NF}' pkg.conf \
| sed 's/ /{i/;s/$/\nd}/' \
| sed -f- pkg.conf.new
```

The first sed script will transform the output to

```
20{issl_cipher 'ECDHJES128:ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES:DH+AESGCM:DH+AES256:RSA+AES :RSA+AESGCMHaNULL:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS:!3DESHSSLv3');
d}
```

Which tells sed to treat line 20 specially: `i` is for *insert*, and `d` for delete which removes the original contents of the line.

Comment: I'm betting we could do this without the awk call entirely, but I have deadlines that won't give me time to play with it. :(

Comment: @PaulHodges: I'd start with `grep -n` rather than `awk`, but I'm not sure what the actual format of the line is :)

Comment: I was thinking since you're using sed already, why add another program invocation? sed can handle the filtering too.

Comment: @PaulHodges: True, and `=` prints the current line number.